# Selecting dictionary items programatically in Swift / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui

I have an API that is returning a dictionary of object items that are variable, based on a users regional access in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "region": "Alaska",
    "cities": ["Anchorage","Juneau","Fairbanks", etc..],
  },
  {
    "region": "Michigan",
    "cities": ["Detroit","Grand Rapids","Warren city", etc..],
  }
]
```

I am trying to find a way to set the regions to an array for a picker, and following a selection from the first picker, enable a second picker with the city options.

To do this I have set regions in userdefaults as an array and I'm mapping it as follows (WORKING):

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State region: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        let regions = response.map{$0.region}

        Picker("Region", selection: $region) {
            ForEach(regions, id: \.self) {
               Text("\($0)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now on a change event of the above picker, I need to enable a second picker and populate it with the cities value from the response, what's the best way to go about this? Thanks for the help

Comment: The best way is probably to restructure your data first before you use it in a view. The solution that first comes to mind is to create a custom type with properties for region and an array of cities and have an array of that type. Another way is to create a dictionary with region as key and cities as values. Both solution will make it much easier to look up the cities for a selected region.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have resolved this as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var store = Store()
    @State private var region: String = "All"
    @State private var city: String = "All"
    @State private var showCities: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Search")) {
             
            Picker("Region", selection: $region) {
                ForEach(store.regions ?? ["Nil"], id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: region, perform: { (region) in
                showCities = false
                Task {
                    do
                    {
                        try await store.fetchCities(region: region)
                        showCities = true
                    } catch {
                        print("\(error)")
                    }
                }
            })
            
            if showCities {
                Picker("City", selection: $city) {
                    ForEach(store.cities ?? ["Nil"], id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
    }
    .task {
        do
        {
            try await store.fetchRegions()
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Store has the functions necessary to access these details (they are encoded), but I would advise putting them in keychain if the values can alter app performance/functionality:

```
@MainActor
class Store: ObservableObject {

@Published var decodedResponse: AuthenticationResponse?
@Published var statuses: [String]?
@Published var regions: [String]?
@Published var cities: [String]?
    
func fetchRegions() async throws {
    let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "signInResponse") as! Data
    let decoded = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(AuthenticationResponse.self, from: data)
    var options = decoded.locations.map{$0.name}
    options.insert("All", at: 0)
    regions = options
}

func fetchCities(region: String) async throws {
    print("[VIEW] region in fetch \(region)")
    
    let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "signInResponse") as! Data
    let decoded = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(AuthenticationResponse.self, from: data)
    var options = decoded.locations.first(where: {$0.name == region})?.set
    options?.insert("All", at: 0)
    cities = options
}
```

Hope this helps someone. I'm no expert :)